# GridGain cache shared on multiple computers do not work

Tags: java, caching, gridgain

I am having a proof of concept from GridGain 6.1.9 that it meets of our requirements, we have evaluated EhCache then InfiniSpan before that, now we are evaluating GridGain.

I have wrote the sample code below for executing a shared cache between to computers(with there own seprate JVMs) which will have a cache shared b/w them.

```
try ( Grid grid = GridGain.start("{GRIDGAIN_HOME}/examples/config/example-cache.xml") ) {
            final GridCache<Integer, String> cache = grid.cache("partitioned");

            String oldVal = cache.put(1, "1");
            boolean success = cache.putx(2, "2");
            success = cache.putxIfAbsent(3, "3");

            System.out.println("Current Value : " + cache.get(3) );
        }
```

I have used "example-cache.xml" config file which comes in the GridGain package. with only "partitioned" cache config ( other caches are removed ). I also added "GridMulticastDiscoverySpi" in order to discover nodes automatically in multiple/distributed computers.

I used this [Blog post and video as guide](http://gridgain.blogspot.com/2014/06/distributed-caching-in-5-minutes.html).
But few things are confusing as those are not clearly shown in the video

1. whether he was using one jvm or multiple
2. xml config file was modified or untouched
3. did he started first node on remote computer or current computer
4. if he was using multicast discovery spi then what are xml configurations

First I have started GridGain Node on remote computer with following command : ggstart.bat examples/config/example-cache.xml
which displays following output.

```
 .....        
[13:43:51] GridGain node started OK (id=8c8758d1)  
[13:43:51] Topology snapshot [ver=1, nodes=1, CPUs=2, heap=1.0GB]
```

Second I ran the above code from Eclipse then it displayed following output

```
 .....
 [13:45:26] GridGain node started OK (id=8c8758d1)
 [13:45:26] Topology snapshot [ver=1, nodes=1, CPUs=2, heap=0.24GB]
 Current Value : 3
 [13:45:34] GridGain node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:07:897]
```

Note that from both outputs it displays "nodes=1". but in the video number of nodes were increased when more nodes got started and remaining nodes were notified about newly started node. It did not happened to me at all.

On my side both computers are connected with the LAN on same network and both can ping each other. Firewall is turned off on both sides.

I have went through many forums but so far I have not been able to find any sample of how to share a single cache among two or more physical computers, I need help, can any body guide on this.

Regards
-WA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the configuration for node discovery. In `example-cache.xml` configuration, please make changes as specified in [Automatic Node Discovery](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Automatic+Node+Discovery) section in documentation.

Also, you should remove `localHost` setting from `GridConfiguration` as well because it points to `127.0.0.1` in the `example-cache.xml` configuration file.